# Как вывести NULL в столбце, когда зависящий от него столбец отсутствует в выборке

Tags: sql

[image: Схема БД]

Мне необходимо для всех отделов(DEPARTMENTS) компании вывести название отдела(DEPARTMENTS.department_name) и фамилию (EMPLOYEES.last_name) его менеджера.
Если отдел не имеет менеджера, то второй столбец должен содержать NULL.

Запрос

SELECT department_name, last_name
FROM DEPARTMENTS, EMPLOYEES
WHERE DEPARTMENTS.manager_id = EMPLOYEES.employee_id

Естественно выводит имена департаментов и имена менеджеров для тех департаментов, где есть менеджер(т.е. DEPARTMENTS.manager_id is not null)

Как выполнить условие задания?

Comment: Никогда так не делайте! Изучите join'ы. Ваш запрос очень и очень не оптимальный. При большом количестве данных и запросов вы заставите страдать ваш сервер. По сути в этом запросе вы говорите СУБД: "возьми каждую строку из одной таблицы и сопоставь с каждой другой строкой в другой. А _потом_ выбери те, где два поля совпадают". В итоге, придётся перебираться n*m записей, где n и m - количество строк в таблицах. Хорошо, если ваша СУБД достаточно умна, чтобы оптимизировать запрос. А если нет?

Comment: @vtvz_ru то, что написано выше - совершенно нормальный синтаксис join для Oracle. Да, именно так - таблицы через запятую, а все условия в where. Так даже можно outer join писать если в условии ставить плюсик рядом с равенством с нужной стороны ;) Это старый синтаксис Oracle, но он работает и поддерживается.

Comment: [Ответ про NULL заодно в другой теме. Читайте про (+) синтаксис](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462735/sql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5/)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT department_name, last_name 
FROM DEPARTMENTS 
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES ON DEPARTMENTS.manager_id = EMPLOYEES.employee_id
```