# SQL замена значения атрибута в результирующей выборке

Tags: sql

[image: Схема БД]

Для этой таблицы я пишу запрос (в оракловском, нативном синтаксисе)

```sql
SELECT 
  EMPLOYEES.last_name as employee_name,
  EMPLOYEES.manager_id as employee_manager,
  DEPARTMENTS.manager_id as department_manager 
FROM
  EMPLOYEES,
  DEPARTMENTS
WHERE 
(
  EMPLOYEES.department_id = DEPARTMENTS.department_id AND
  EMPLOYEES.manager_id <> DEPARTMENTS.manager_id
);
```

Как подставить в столбцы `employee_manager` и `department_manager` вместо `id` значение `last_name`, соответствующие этим `id`?

Answer (score 1):

Непонятен вопрос. Что означает

> "Как подставить в столбцы employee_name и department_name вместо id
>   значение last_name, соответствующие этим id?"

У Вас же уже написано `EMPLOYEES.last_name as employee_name`, т.е. в столбец `employee_name` подставлется `last_name`.

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ**

Просто ещё два раза добавьте таблицу сотрудников:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEES.last_name as employee_name, 
       emp_man.last_name AS employee_manager, 
       dept_man.last_name as department_manager
  FROM EMPLOYEES, DEPARTMENTS,
       employees emp_man,
       employees dept_man
 WHERE (EMPLOYEES.department_id = DEPARTMENTS.department_id 
   AND EMPLOYEES.manager_id != DEPARTMENTS.manager_id
   AND employees.manager_id = emp_man.EMPLOYEE_ID (+)
   AND DEPARTMENTS.manager_id = dept_man.EMPLOYEE_ID (+))
```

Comment: Исправил опечатку в вопросе, спасибо